# JmsTemplate not closing Connection after upgrading

Tags: hornetq, spring-jms

We are experiencing two problems after upgrading:

1.) Spring 3.1 to 4.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

2.) JBoss Messaging Service 5.1.2 to HornetQ-2.4.5.Final

## Problems are:

1. CachingConnectionFactory does not re-fresh Connection & stale Sessions upon a HornetQ server failure & restart (e.g., I get "Session is closed"
   errors all day on every send)
2. JmsTemplate (in a non-caching CF) does not close the JMS Connection

Our use of CachingConnectionFactory and JmsTemplate was flawless for years on the old platform.

After upgrading, I now have lost both my CachingConnectionFactory and my JmsTemplate!  A few question then:

**Is JmsTemplate only good inside a JTA transaction, so it can use the TxnSync facility to track the Jms Resources?**

**Is there a bug in HornetQ & Spring CachingConnectionFactory I need to workaround somehow?**

**I send several messages to different Destinations, outside of a JTA transaction.  Is this not possible anymore?**

```
2015-03-02 11:30:35,325 WARN  (Finalizer) [org.hornetq.jms.client] HQ122000: I''m closing a JMS connection you left open. Please make sure you close all JMS connections explicitly before letting them go out of scope! see stacktrace to find out where it was created
java.lang.Exception
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnection.<init>(HornetQConnection.java:151)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:722)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:112)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:107)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.access$600(JmsTemplate.java:90)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$JmsTemplateResourceFactory.createConnection(JmsTemplate.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:312)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:480)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:568)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:657)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:648)
```

My steps are:

1.) createJMSMessage() - uses JmsTemplate SessionCallback - see below.

2.) populate the JMS message

3.) sendNow(Message) - again, uses JmsTemplate

Here is the create message code using a SessionCallback.

```
public Message createJMSMessage(int messageType) {
    Message message = null;

    init();

    try {
        switch (messageType) {
            case JMS_MESSAGE_TYPE_OBJECT:
                message = (Message)jmsTemplate.execute(new SessionCallback<Object>() {
                    public Object doInJms(Session session) throws JMSException {
                        return session.createObjectMessage();
                    }
                }, false);
                //message = jmsProducer.createObjectMessage();
                break;

            default:
            .... Unknown type, log error here
        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new SubSystemException("Failed to create message: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }


return message;}
```

Here is the send() code:

```
public void sendNow(Message message) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("sendNow : Enter [" + destinationLocation+"]");
        }

        if (!JmsUtils.isPayloadNull(message)) {
            init();

            try {
                // Take properties from the Message and apply to our send()
                int priority = message.getJMSPriority();
                long expiration = message.getJMSExpiration();

                if (priority < 0) {
                    priority = Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY;
                }   

                if (expiration < 0) {
                    expiration = Message.DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE;
                }

                jmsTemplate.setPriority(priority);
                jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(expiration);
                jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(isPubSub);  // false for Queues and true for Topics

                jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
            } catch(JMSException ex) {
                throw new SubSystemException("sendNow() failed with JMSException. Details >>>> "+JmsUtils.toString(message), ex);
            }
        } else {
            if (log.isWarnEnabled()) {
                // Spring JMS listener container will puke on a null payload anyway, so
                // we just don't send it.  Spring JMS listener error is not descriptive enough
                // and at least here, we have more details on the message to log
                log.warn("sendNow : [" + destinationLocation+"] Payload is NULL.  "
                        + "Message not sent.  Details >>>> "+JmsUtils.toString(message));
            }
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("sendNow : Exit [" + destinationLocation+"]");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are creating the message with one session and sending it with another. You can't do that. Please fix your code first and let's see what happens.

Comment: I wondered about that!  When using JmsTemplate & NO JTA, that makes sense - Spring would not be able to track the Session across separate create JMS message and the separate send.  However, when inside a JTA boundary, the ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession() should return the same Session for each SessionCallback call, right?

Comment: Yes but it's a bit weird to rely on that if you ask me.